# concatenation of decimal and varchar in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, concatenation

I have 2 columns in my table :

```
PER_DAY (DECIMAL(10,2))
DESCP   (VARCHAR)
```

I want to concat the two columns in my query...

For Ex:

```
PER_DAY=0.5  DESCP='ABCDEFGHIJ'
```

I want them to be displayed as

```
0.5-ABCDEFGHIJ
```

I'm using IBM DB2.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
select char(per_day) || DESCP from table;
```

EDIT:

```
select CAST(per_day AS VARCHAR(13)) || '-' || DESCP from table;
```

Comment: I tried it but it is giving the result as : 00000000.50 -'ABCDEFGHIJ'

Comment: I tried it....But it shows an error like this:   A value with data type "SYSIBM.DECIMAL" cannot be CAST to type
"SYSIBM.VARCHAR"

Comment: @Yahia use VARCHAR(13) for the CAST - 10 for integer part, 1 for dot and 2 characters for the decimal part, else overflow may occur

Comment: @niktrs: thanks :-) @ sagarg: please try again with VARCHAR(13)

Comment: @yahia         It is again giving tyhe same error like :A value with data type "SYSIBM.DECIMAL" cannot be CAST to type "SYSIBM.VARCHAR".  SQLSTATE=42846

Comment: then I am out of ideas - don't have a DB2 at hand but from what I read DB2 isn't big on formatting data via SQL :-(

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select trim(varchar(per_day)) || '-' || DESCP from table;
```